# Grails many to many using a third 'join' class

Tags: grails, many-to-many, grails-orm

I read that a m:m relationship often means there is a third class that isn't yet required. So I have m:m on `User` and `Project`, and I created a third domain class, `ProjectMembership`

The three domains are as follows (minimized for illustration purposes):

User

```
class User {

String name 

static hasMany = [projectMemberships : ProjectMembership]
}
```

Project Membership

```
class ProjectMembership {

static constraints = {          
}

static belongsTo = [user:User, project:Project]
}
```

Project:

```
class Project {

String name

static hasMany = [projectMemberships : ProjectMembership]

     static constraints = { 
     }
}
```

If I have the ID of the user, how can I get a list of `Project` objects that they are assigned to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a handful of ways - here are a couple:

```
def user = User.get(userId)
ProjectMembership.findAllByUser(user).collect { it.project }
```

or to avoid the query for the User:

```
ProjectMembership.withCriteria {
    user {
        eq('id', userId)
    }
}.collect { it.project }
```

Be wary of queries that'll return large result sets - you'll end up with a huge in-memory list of project objects.

Comment: thanks! worked perfect, just one small adjustment to your solution for reference for anyone else, `findAllByUser` took a user object as a param, but thanks, it was mainly the syntax and not knowing about the collect method

Comment: My bad on that, I had a meeting to run to and didn't put a lot of thought into it. I've updated the answer with a couple of options.